# How to connect ssis with elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, ssis, elasticsearch-plugin

I would like to know how to connect SSIS  with ElasticSearch for import/export data. Is there any oldedb/odbc driver for elasticsearch ? any (.net/c#) script to import or export data to and from elasticsearch using SSIS? Thanks in advance.
Much appreciated.